# FDMQ8203 vs. FDMQ8205/A

Tags: poe

From the [appnote](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND6234-D.PDF) FDMQ8205/A is almost identical to FDMQ8203 except the externa circuitry is no longer required.

I am curious if anyone knows why in the FDMQ8205/A design VOUTN is NOT connected to GND but FDMQ8203 shows VOUTN connected to GND. Was this intentional or just a small mistake in the datasheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks entirely intentional to me. In the diagram for the newer chip, they didn't want to presume anything about the nature of the blue box, so they keep VOUTP and VOUTN floating with respect to ground.

This allows, for example, the DC-DC converter inside the blue box to be an isolating converter (or not).